# Using jQuery: How can a value be updated to match an elements visibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visibility, show-hide

How to update a value based on an elements visibility?

**HTML**

```
<div class="Wrap">
    <h1 class="Btn">CLICK ME</h1>
    <div class="Body">CONTENT</div>
    <input type="text"></input>
</div>
```

***NOTE:*** This code block is duplicate several times.

---

**JQUERY**

I realise I can accompplish this using jquery :visible selector.

```
//Find clicked element
$('.Wrap').find('.Btn').click(function () {
  //Find next element named...
  var $body = $(this).siblings('.Body').slideToggle('fast');
  //Show /Hide
  $('.Body').not($body).slideUp('fast');

  //Find if element is visible
  var value = $(this).siblings('.Body').is(':visible');
  //Set value to match visibility
  $(this).siblings('input').val(value);
});
```

---

**TWO PROBLEMS**

1. hidden element is initially reported as visible.
2. value is not being updated on each click.

## DEMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait until the sliding animation is completed. The [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/#slideDown-duration-complete) callback will help:

```
$(this).siblings('.Body').slideToggle('fast', function() {
    var value = $(this).is(':visible');
    $(this).siblings('input').val(value);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vVvX6/3/